# You wouldn't want to touch me

Tags: riddle

> My prefix is an organ,
>   My suffix is an officer,
>   My infix sounds Russian,
>   You touch me everyday,
>   But if I was someone else's you wouldn't want to touch me.
>
> **What am I?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer could be,

> Handkerchief

Prefix - Organ,

> Hand

Suffix - Officer,

> Chief

You touch me everyday,

> One uses it everyday

But if I was someone else's you wouldn't want to touch me.

> People usually do not use someone Else's Handkerchief.

Not sure about the Russian part since I do not know any Russian References.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Kerch is the word you would want to look into, that belongs to Russia.

Answer (score 8):

I think the answer might be

> [Mouthguard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouthguard)

My prefix is an organ,

> Mouth

My suffix is an officer,

> Guard

My infix sounds Russian,

> 'thguar' sounds a bit like Tsar.

You touch me everyday,

> I don't own one but those who do often sleep with them in or use them to play contact sport.

But if I was someone else's you wouldn't want to touch me.

> Touching somebody else's mouthguard seems unhygienic.

Comment: +1, interesting, but not the answer i'm looking for. Except for the Russian part, your answer is the closest !